# Temporarily stop clients from connecting to a socket

Tags: php, sockets

I need to make a script that is server and client at the same time.

This needs to alternate from listening to trying to connect.

Is there a way to temporarily block any client from connecting while it proceeds to client mode and attempts to connect?

As far as I have noticed there is only a permanent way to stop this that would involve starting to listen again and I am trying to avoid that.

The idea is that this will run on multiple servers and it will have to connect to itself.

Each time a connection is made each party removes the other from list of (clients/destinations) once they exchange what they need to exchange.

So I need a way to block the listener while it attempts a connection cause on rare occasions two attempt connection to each other at the exact same time and bought hang waiting to be picked up but that does not happen.

Comment: Voted to move to dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: @njk Why? There is nothing about databases or administration in the question.

Comment: @EJP It seems to me that blocking sockets while a connection is taking place should be at the session layer, not at the application layer.

Comment: Still it has nothing to do with databases.

Comment: Nothing to do with a database... my two cents ;p

Comment: Why can't you simply close the listening socket and open it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either do:

- close() the listen socket (and maybe reopen it when needed)
- if the listen socket becomes readable, don't call accept() yet (you can get away with this for a few seconds, but it does use OS resources)
- do call accept(), but immediately close() the resulting socket. (this is rather rude...)

The above three options are from the systemcall/OS level. I don't know how PHP implements (or wraps) them.

Comment: After rereading your question I think the only possible option would be accept()+lookup(ip)+close(). The client IP-address is only available *after* the connection request has been accepted. The lookup() should inspect a (hash) table of (un)wanted connections, maintained by both the active and passive parts of the program. (this table could be seen as a "work list") BTW: I once used this mechanism to implement an IP-ban function in a server: if the IP exists in the ban-list, just close the socket.

Comment: No, just in ordinary C without threads (for a few hundred non-blocking connections, low bandwidth and relatively small CPU cost per message you don't need threads) . But again: I don't know *how* PHP has wrapped up the socket()/listen()/accept()/select() primitives, but I am sure it has them somehow.